# Launch script after confirming action (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm currently doing my final internship for the Network Administration training at school. And I've been asked to create a simple web page that allows for selecting a range of servers to perform a clean install on. Like: when I select 'Server 1' and 'Server 4' > click 'Submit' > confirm my action > launch VBscript that performs clean install.

What I have so far (also refer to pieces of code at end):
 - Basic welcome text
 - Check boxes
 - Select all (javascript)
 - Continue button
 - When clicking continue button > show warning that asks for confirmation

What I want it to do, is launching the script of the selected box(es) after confirming. Is that possible? I mean, I assume I'll need something else than HTML. Javascript maybe? How would I do such thing?

I'm not a total expert with this stuff, not at all. I do have some experience with HTML and CSS, but Javascript and all that? Nope, not at all. Would be very happy to have some help with this!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Huawei Cleaning Center
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetAllCheckBoxes(FormName, FieldName, CheckValue)
{
    if(!document.forms[FormName])
        return;
    var objCheckBoxes = document.forms[FormName].elements[FieldName];
    if(!objCheckBoxes)
        return;
    var countCheckBoxes = objCheckBoxes.length;
    if(!countCheckBoxes)
        objCheckBoxes.checked = CheckValue;
    else
        // set the check value for all check boxes
        for(var i = 0; i < countCheckBoxes; i++)
            objCheckBoxes[i].checked = CheckValue;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clicked() {
       if (confirm('Weet u zeker dat u wilt doorgaan?')) {
           yourformelement.submit();
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Welkom bij Huawei Cleaning Center!</h1></center>
<br><br>
Kruis één of meerdere van de volgende servers aan waarop u een Clean Install wilt uitvoeren:<br><br>
<form method="GET" action="page17.php" name="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<label for="myCheckbox1">
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox1">
172.16.115.11 </label>
<br>
<label for="myCheckbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="2" id="myCheckbox2">
172.16.115.21 </label>
<br>
<label for="myCheckbox3"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="3" id="myCheckbox3">
172.16.115.31 </label>
<br>
<label for="myCheckbox4"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="4" id="myCheckbox4">
172.16.115.41 </label>
<br><br><input type="submit" id="submit1" onclick="clicked();" value="Doorgaan">
<input type="button" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('myForm', 'myCheckbox', true);" value="Selecteer alles">
<input type="button" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('myForm', 'myCheckbox', false);" value="Deselecteer alles">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far. The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: After confirm(), you can redirect to specific VBscript launch page: window.location.replace("your-page");

Answer (score 0):

Change your js like this. Form gonna submit if you click yes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clicked() {
   var confirmed = confirm('Weet u zeker dat u wilt doorgaan?')
   if (confirmed) {
       yourformelement.submit();
   } else {
       alert('You clicked No');
   }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use JQuery you also could do this:

```
$(yourformelement).submit(function(e){
   var dialogresult = confirm('Confirm');
   if (dialogresult ) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems like you're using PHP. In this case you could try something like this in your php page (`page17.php` as referred in the action attribute):

```
if(!empty($_POST['serverList'])) {
  foreach($_POST['serverList'] as $arg) {
    exec('cscript "path/to/script.vbs" ' . $arg);
  }
}
```

`$_POST['serverList']` contains an array of the checkboxes values and the `foraech` loop will execute a VBscript passing the values as arguments.

Here's a snippet of the JS/CSS/HTML code:

```js
function setCheckboxes(checkboxName, value) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = value;
  }
}

function submitForm(checkboxName) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
      confirmation = confirm('Weet u zeker dat u wilt doorgaan?');
      if (confirmation) {
        return true;
      } else { 
        return false; 
      }
    }
  }
  alert('No server selected!');
  return false;
}
```

```css
.main-heading {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.info {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main-heading">Welkom bij Huawei Cleaning Center!</h1>
<p class="info">
  Kruis één of meerdere van de volgende servers aan waarop u een Clean Install wilt uitvoeren:
</p>
<form method="POST" action="page17.php" name="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <label for="checkbox-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="serverList[]" value="1" id="checkbox-1">
    172.16.115.11
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="checkbox-2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="serverList[]" value="2" id="checkbox-2">
    172.16.115.21
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="checkbox-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="serverList[]" value="3" id="checkbox-3">
    172.16.115.31
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="checkbox-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="serverList[]" value="4" id="checkbox-4">
    172.16.115.41
  </label>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="submitForm('serverList[]');" value="Doorgaan">
  <input type="button" onclick="setCheckboxes('serverList[]', true);" value="Selecteer alles">
  <input type="reset" value="Deselecteer alles">
</form>
```

Hope it helps :)